# FULL JOIN with 3 Tables In Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

can somebody help me to create full join with 3 tables in access? the thriD join will be between my BB table & CC on location.

```
SELECT *
        FROM AA
            JOIN BB ON AA.C_ID = BB.C_ID
    UNION ALL
    SELECT *
        FROM AA
            LEFT JOIN BB ON AA.C_ID = BB.C_ID
        WHERE BB.C_ID IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT *
        FROM AA
            RIGHT JOIN BB ON AA.C_ID = BB.C_ID
        WHERE AA.C_ID IS NULL
```

Thank you

Comment: Why is this tagged with SQL Server and MySQL when you're asking about Access?

Comment: I only see 2 tables AA and BB?

Comment: @rontornambe yes, i have not added it yet and my question is how to add the third table?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested the following code but I believe the idea is to repeat another full join using the third table:

```
SELECT * FROM AA
LEFT JOIN BB ON AA.C_ID = BB.C_ID
WHERE BB.C_ID IS NULL
    UNION ALL
SELECT *
    FROM AA
        RIGHT JOIN BB ON AA.C_ID = BB.C_ID
    WHERE AA.C_ID IS NULL

    UNION ALL

SELECT * FROM CC
LEFT JOIN AA ON AA.C_ID = CC.C_ID
WHERE CC.C_ID IS NULL

    UNION ALL

SELECT *
    FROM AA
    RIGHT JOIN CC ON AA.C_ID = CC.C_ID
    WHERE AA.C_ID IS NULL
```